# Regex unicode - route codeignite

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am working on getting the regex to work but now I am starting to go in circles.
This regex would be used in the codeigniter for the routing purposes, something like:

```
$route['([\p{Ll}\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]+)-(\d+).html'] = "blog/$2";
```

I've got a regex that does what I need to:

```
$pattern  = "/^[\p{Ll}0-9\s\-]+$/u";
```

But for some reason it doesn't want to work in the patten bellow

```
$str="asdбв-37.html";

$pattern  = "#^([\p{Ll}\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]+)-(\d+).html#";

$result = (bool) preg_match($pattern, $str);
if($result)
    echo "$str is composed of Cyrillic and alphanumeric characters\n";
```

My end target is to check that any character, from any language, is written in the lower case, that is why I have used \p{Ll}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern which is working but for `asdбв-37.html` doesn't allow periods. Try adding them in:

```
^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s.-]+$
```

[Also, you don't need to escape the `-` if it's at the end or beginning of a character class to change its meaning to literal.]

Comment: "/^[\p{Ll}0-9\s\-]+$/u" - this seems to do what I am looking for. I am finding tricky on how to apply above to - "#^([\p{Ll}0-9\s\-]+)-(\d+).html#";

Comment: @user1652382 You need to escape the dot if it's not within a character class. But it works: [link](http://www.regex101.com/r/rN2bN7). And the first regex in your comment should really be `^[\p{Ll}0-9\s.-]+$`

Comment: Ok, it works fine. You got to have this 'u' at the end. I will have to modify that code... #^([\p{Ll}0-9\s\-]+)-(\d+)\.html$#u. I was searching for a way of not doing it, guess gonna have to do it :)

Comment: @user1652382 Yea, I guess you can't do otherwise :(. Was there any reason you were avoiding the `u` flag?